# Saving TextField Entries from a Modal View Controller to Core Data Separate Entities

Tags: ios, entity-framework, core-data, nsmanagedobject, categories

I have a basic, but working app that I'm working on. The premise is:

There is a Table View Controller with a plus button in the Navigation Controller, the user presses that plus button and it brings up a Modal View; the user is asked to type in information into 4 text fields for the following information: name, amount, title and date.

I have the following model:

Transaction Entity with wasCompleted attribute
Person entity with name attribute
Action entity with title attribute
Item entity with amount attribute

The transaction Entity has a relationship to Person, Action and Item.

When the user presses save, I have the following code which saves all of this information to the Core Data Database:

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    NSManagedObject *transaction = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Transaction" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSManagedObject *person = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSManagedObject *actionEvent = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Occasion" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSManagedObject *amountType = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [person setValue:self.nameTextField.text forKey:@"name"];
    [occasionEvent setValue:self.actionTextField.text forKey:@"title"];
    [occasionEvent setValue:self.dateTextField.text forKey:@"dateOfEvent"];
    [amountType setValue:self.itemTextField.text forKey:@"amount"];

    [transaction setValue:person forKey:@"whoBy"];
    [transaction setValue:actionEvent forKey:@"occasion"];
    [transaction setValue:amountType forKey:@"item"];

}
```

This works very well, but of course, it's not Object Oriented programming in it's finest and it's not great code with setValues, etc.

What I want to achieve is in the Save button is:

Call the Transaction NSManagedObject Subclass to create a new transaction where I will check if that transaction exists and if it does not, I will create the Transaction object with the wasCompleted attribute, which then calls the Person NSManagedObject class to create that attribute. The Transaction NSManagedObject subclass also of course calls the Action and Item classes to do that.

I figure I'd do this using Categories (based on watching the CS193p iTunes U Course) and I've spent hours trying to figure out what I actually pass. From the Save Button, I've got the NSManagedObjectContext which is part of what I figure I'd pass (though I'm using the NSManagedObjectContext from the AppDelegate), but I honestly have no idea what I'd pass to the Transaction NSManagedObject Subclass.

My questions are:
1) Should I create a Dictionary/Array to HOLD all of the details that the user has added in the Modal View class and pass that across to the Transaction NSManagedObject subclass? or,

2) Is there a better way to pass information added in from the user across to the Transaction NSManagedObject subclass? or,

3) Should I call the Person, Action and Item entities from the Add Entry Modal View, or from the Transaction NSManagedObject Subclass?

4) Is creating categories the right way to go?

5) Are you able to provide a simple one-liner sample code of what I'd pass through to the Transaction Entity?

Any help on this would be massively appreciated. I've been stuck for hours and I figure it cannot be that difficult, but I'm just lost! I'm a clear newbie to iOS Development!

EDIT:

I want to provide a bit more information. I have the NSManagedObject Subclasses for each of the entities (Person, Transaction, etc) but they're currently not really doing anything apart from holding the attributes as properties. In the TableView and the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, I am calling transaction.whoBy.name etc and that is all working. With the latest response from Mundi, I find that very helpful but just require a small bit of information please. The Modal view will absolutely be used to Add new entries, but also to Edit existing entries so as you, I'll have to check if it's a new entry, or an existing entry to then pass that data across.

How would I go about doing something like this:

1) If object does not exist, create new one with each of the attributes. 
2) If it does exist, call that attribute. I see from your code that it is related to:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = transaction.managedObjectContext;
```

So in this case, in the Add Entry, I just need to add some validation checks (because if I have two entries by the same name, I do not want the NAME tab to display that information twice, it should be one entry, etc), I would stick the code I have now for creating the Transactions, Persons, Actions from the save method but add those additional validation checks? Sorry, just a bit lost!

I completely understand the mention of passing existing data, but in code, I'm just not sure how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that creating the entity in the entity class itself, or even in a category, is a good pattern to follow. In principle you are doing the right thing by creating and linking the entities in the controller (that is what controllers are for).

What you should do is create `NSManagedObject` subclasses (via the Xcode command from the Core Data model editor). This provides a true reflection of the object graph and results in very nice and readable code.

If your modal view controller is there to *create or edit* a Transaction instance I would pass the existing or a new transaction object to it. You can get the managed object context from the instance itself.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = transaction.managedObjectContext;
```

If the passed transaction object has data, you can populate your text fields with the existing data. If after editing "cancel" is pressed instead of "save", you simply delete the new transaction or leave the existing one unchanged.

The `NSManagedObject` subclasses allow you to set the attributes and relationships in much more readable form. For example:

```
person.name = self.nameTextField.text;
transaction.whoBy = person;
// etc.
```

BTW, I think you maybe meant `actionEvent` when you wrote `occasionEvent` in your code.

One more thing: the `dateOfEvent` property of the Occasion entity is surely of type `NSDate`, not a string. So you could convert the date from the text (in the text field) to a proper `NSDate` type. While this can be done, a better solution is to use a `UIDatePicker` to select the date. As of iOS 7 the picker should be integrated into the controller's view along with the text fields rather than as a separate modal view controller.

Comment: Dear @Mundi - thanks for the brilliant reply - that is very helpful. 

That's very interesting that I'm on the right path; I always thought creating a Transaction object should be in the Transaction class but that's really interesting. I have the NSManagedObject subclasses of the Transaction, Person, etc Entities but they're currently not doing anything.. though in the cellForRowAtIndexPath, I am calling transaction.name, etc so I see it working with that.. I'm going to edit the original question to fill more information in there because it makes sense what you've mentioned..

Comment: Hi Mundi - I've just added a bit more information (and a few more questions) because I'm just a small bit unsure of the next steps - I want to add validation so I'm either creating a new object or passing an existing one.. so any further help would be massively appreciated! 

Also, absolutely - typo on my part with the action, occasionEvent and thanks for the NSDate suggestion - that's another task I have to get onto because I set it up as a string just to make sure it works but I will indeed look into the UIPicker - thanks again